# geany error "Program exited with code: 126"

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, geany

I'm trying to program a simple hello world program using c++/geany on the raspberry pi. However, when I try to run it. The output terminal says "Program exited with code: 126". Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZs02.png)

I tried running sudo commands like sudo apt-get update/upgrade, clean, upgrade --fix-missing. Reinstalling geany. I tried using codeblocks ide and had no luck.

Comment: Why do you read only the last line? The dump has the useful information if you read it from the beginning.

Comment: what do you mean by the dump?

Comment: Program outputs.

Comment: All the outputs are in the photo. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZs02.png). I can't find anymore information

Comment: @bc345 This part `HelloWorld: Permission denied.`

Comment: @bc345 It means you don't have the necessary permission to run the program you have created. That is why you get the error code 126.

Comment: @john do you know what could be causing that issue?

Comment: @bc345 No idea since I know nothing about geany, but the first thing to do is find out what the permissions are. What output do you see if you execute the command `ls -l ./HelloWorld`?

Comment: @john it tells me that there is no such directory

Comment: @bc345 So you need to execute that command from the directory where HelloWorld is located (I'm assuming it hasn't been deleted).

Answer (score 0):

I had to "build"/compile it first on geany before I ran the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the file as ".py"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).